# In python, how to break list of strings into list of list of strings?

Tags: python, list, file-io, cherrypy

I am running a server with cherrypy and python script. Currently, there is a web page containing data of a list of people, which i need to get. The format of the web page is as follow:

```
www.url1.com, firstName_1, lastName_1
www.url2.com, firstName_2, lastName_2
www.url3.com, firstName_3, lastName_3
```

I wish to display the list of names on my own webpage, with each name hyperlinked to their corresponding website.

I have read the webpage into a list with the following method:

```
@cherrypy.expose
    def receiveData(self):
        """ Get a list, one per line, of currently known online addresses,
            separated by commas.
        """

        method = "whoonline"
        fptr = urllib2.urlopen("%s/%s" % (masterServer, method))
        data = fptr.readlines()
        fptr.close()

        return data
```

But I don't know how to break the list into a list of lists at where the comma are. The result should give each smaller list three elements; URL, First Name, and Last Name. So I was wondering if anyone could help.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over fptr, no need to call `readlines()`

```
data = [line.split(', ') for line in fptr]
```

Comment: would this only give me a list, instead of a list of lists? So I'll need to remember that element 0,3,6 are URLs, 2,4,7 are FirstNames, and 3,5,8 are LastNames?

Comment: @Synia, `line.split()` will return a list. The list comprehension makes a list of those lists

Answer (score 2):

You need the `split(',')` method on each string:

```
data = [ line.split(',') for line in fptr.readlines() ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lists = []
for line in data:
   lists.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you data is a big 'ole string (potentially with leading or trailing spaces), do it this way:

```
lines="""    www.url1.com, firstName_1, lastName_1
www.url2.com, firstName_2     , lastName_2   
www.url3.com, firstName_3, lastName_3           """

data=[]
for line in lines.split('\n'):
    t=[e.strip() for e in line.split(',')]
    data.append(t)

print data
```

Out:

```
[['www.url1.com', 'firstName_1', 'lastName_1'], ['www.url2.com', 'firstName_2', 
  'lastName_2'], ['www.url3.com', 'firstName_3', 'lastName_3']]
```

Notice the leading and trailing spaces are removed.